# what grunt task actually does the proper indent

Tags: replace, gruntjs, indentation

I've specified an region in my `index.html` where by cordova/phonegap specific scripts have to be included...

```
<!-- cordova:js -->
<!-- endcordova -->
```

But note here that this is usually intended as shown below:

[image]

I use a `grunt-replace` task for this. The configuration for this is generated dynamically but putting it down anyway for the sake of making sense...

```
replace: {
    plugins: {
        options: {
            usePrefix: false,
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: '<!-- cordova:js -->',
                    replace: '<!-- cordova:js -->;line1;line2;line3;'.replace(';', '\n')
                }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            //files you want to replace...
        ]
    }
}
```

The final output looks like this:

[image]

I am looking to get this indented properly like below:

[image]

What is the appropriate task for this?

Answer (score 0):

call [grunt-jsbeautifier](https://github.com/vkadam/grunt-jsbeautifier) on your final html.